# How to disable nVIDIA in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am using dual OS (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) in my laptop Dell inspiron14.
It has two VGA (Intel Graphics and nVIDIA)

When I work in Windows 7, it using Intel Graphics and When I work in Ubuntu, it using nVIDIA because of this when I use Ubuntu battary goes down quickly.

How to **disable nVIDIA** and make it to **use Intel Graphics**?

Please help me in this case.
I couldn't not find best way by search over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

1. Shut down the machine completely.
2. Boot up and go into the BIOS
3. Disable nvidia
4. Continue booting

### Done!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: I try to do as you said above, but I could not find any function to disable nVidia in BIOS Please tell me, Where I can find that option or tell me some other way to disable nVidia.

Comment: I don't have a Dell: I have another brand of laptop, so if you cannot find this option in your BIOS, I cannot help you and you should [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).  I'm running with my Intel Graphics enabled, which disables my NVidia...